# IBM Worklight JSON Store with Sync using HTTP Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

How to load data from database on load of the application?
How to push data to database?
The sample given by IBM Worklight helps to load data from JSON store, but how to use HTTP Adapter to fetch data and load?

Comment: State clearly what you are trying to achieve and what you have done. Get JSONStore related sample from here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#setup

Comment: Did you try adapters?

Answer (score 2):

Read the [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_class_wl_jsonstore.html) and look at the JSONStore [getting started modules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html) and code samples.

> How to load data from database on load of the application?

Use [load](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_load.html). You can also do it with [WL.Client.invokeProcedure](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_invokeprocedure.html) or [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and then call [add](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_add.html) with the response data.

> How to push data to database?

Use [push](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_push.html) or get the documents with local-only changes with [getPushRequired](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_getpushreuired.html) and use [WL.Client.invokeProcedure](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_invokeprocedure.html) or [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send data back to the backend.

All the methods linked above have examples. You should be able to figure out how to adapt those examples to your needs.